# Slurm not writing batch script log files

Tags: slurm

When running the batch script

```
#!/bin/sh
#SBATCH -n 1
#SBATCH --output=serial_test_%j.log 
hostname
echo "test" > test.log
```

the serial_test_142.log file is not written, and test.log is not written. /var/log/slurm_JobComp lists

```
JobId=142 UserId=ebryer(1000) GroupId=ebryer(1000) Name=hw.sh JobState=FAILED Partition=n TimeLimit=UNLIMITED StartTime=2021-11-30T13:52:14 EndTime=2021-11-30T13:52:14 NodeList=n2 NodeCnt=1 ProcCnt=1 WorkDir=/home/ebryer ReservationName= Gres= Account= QOS= WcKey= Cluster=unknown SubmitTime=2021-11-30T13:52:12 EligibleTime=2021-11-30T13:52:12 DerivedExitCode=0:0 ExitCode=1:0
```

And /var/log/slurmctld lists

```
[2021-11-30T13:52:12.678] _slurm_rpc_submit_batch_job: JobId=142 InitPrio=4294901740 usec=2069
[2021-11-30T13:52:14.894] sched: Allocate JobId=142 NodeList=n2 #CPUs=1 Partition=n
[2021-11-30T13:52:14.894] prolog_running_decr: Configuration for JobId=142 is complete
[2021-11-30T13:52:14.962] _job_complete: JobId=142 WEXITSTATUS 1
[2021-11-30T13:52:14.962] _job_complete: JobId=142 done
```

If I change the batch script line to `#SBATCH --output=/tmp/serial_test_%j.log` the exit status of the job is 0 as shown in /var/log/slurm_JobComp:

```
[2021-11-30T13:52:35.265] _slurm_rpc_submit_batch_job: JobId=143 InitPrio=4294901739 usec=2067
[2021-11-30T13:52:35.970] sched: Allocate JobId=143 NodeList=n2 #CPUs=1 Partition=n
[2021-11-30T13:52:35.971] prolog_running_decr: Configuration for JobId=143 is complete
[2021-11-30T13:52:36.247] _job_complete: JobId=143 WEXITSTATUS 0
[2021-11-30T13:52:36.247] _job_complete: JobId=143 done
```

And scontrol shows it succeeded, `JobState=COMPLETED Reason=None Dependency=(null)`, but there is no log file in /tmp or test.log output. Can someone suggest why this occurs?

Answer (score 0):

/home wasn't mounted on the nodes. It wrote to n5:/tmp when I defined the log file go there, which I should have expected.